# Android Studio NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, android

I've finished an app and have been attempting to have that app log some data in a text file. I have a few questions about creating files and file paths with Android Studio. I'm not well versed in the editor so perhaps my questions are simple. I'm logging the data in an activity that extends MainActivity, declared as LoggerActivity.

```
public class LoggerActvitivty extends MainActivity{
public boolean bNewUser = true;
public String sFileName;

public void writeToFile(HashMap hmSaleToSave) {
    if (bNewUser) {
        System.out.println(hmSaleToSave);
        sFileName = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Sales-" + LocalDateTime.now() + ".txt";

        try {
            if(!Files.exists(Paths.get(sFileName))) {
                Files.createFile(Paths.get(sFileName));
                Files.write(Paths.get(sFileName), sFileName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }

            System.out.println("FILE WRITE EXECUTED");
            System.out.println("Location" + sFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

}

Nothing crash's, but I believe I'm providing a null directory resulting in this logcat error

```
W/System.err: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Download/Sales-2021-08-16T07:44:36.321.txt
```

I would like the logs to go to my tablets download directory. My first question is should I be using a different method to get my directory rather than through Enviornment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS? Additionally if the path doesn't exist Files.createFile(....) should create the path too? Or does that just create the file at the specified path (sFileName)?

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` is not a filesystem path; you cannot concatenate other things onto it to create a filesystem path. On older devices, you would pass it as a parameter to [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you for the info and link, I will follow that example.